# spring data insert if not exists entity with field

Tags: database, jpa, spring-data

Can anyone recommend a way to perform inserts in a database table via spring data jpa  (in a clustered environment) only when the entry doesn't already exist in the database?

As an example situation, take a database with *message* and *email_address* tables. When a new message  addressed to 'user@so.com' is added to the *message* table, a check will be done in the *email_address* table whether the email 'user@so.com' exists in the *email_address* and if it doesn't, it gets added to the database. Afterwards the email address entity field is set on the message entity and subsequently the message entity is saved.

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EmailAddress emailAddress;   

    private String content;

}


@Entity
public class EmailAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    // a unique constraint exists on this field on the database
    private String email;
}
```

What should there be done with the spring data jpa EmailAddressRepository to avoid database exceptions that can occur when concurrently trying to insert entities with the same email address?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a check inside a [@PrePersist](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) annotated method in your entity. Other than that, I don't think JPA or spring-data provide something out of the box for that.